# Moving files in python based on file and folder name

Tags: python-3.x, directory, shutil

Relatively new to python ( not using it everyday ). However I am trying to simplify some things. I basically have Keys which have long names however a subset of the key ( or file name ) has the same sequence of the associated folder.{excuse the indentation, it is properly indented.} I.E

file1 would be: 101010-CDFGH-8271.dat and folder is CDFGH-82
file2 would be: 101010-QWERT-7425.dat and folder is QWERT-74

```
import os
import glob
import shutil


files = os.listdir("files/location")
dest_1 = os.listdir("dest/location")

for f in files:
    file = f[10:21]

for d in dest_1:
    dire = d

if file == dire:
    shutil.move(file, dest_1)
```

The code runs with no errors, however nothing moves. Look forward to your reply and chance to learn.

Sorry updated the format.

Comment: also those arent the names of the files but that range is what I would need.

Comment: Consider using the correct indentation, so your if-statement falls inside a for loop (and probably, a nested for-loop).

Comment: Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting to learn about code formatting. Without your code formatted, I have had to guess what the indentation was, so I assumed the most basic.

Comment: Your mistake is likely that you use the subset of the filename to assign to `file` (to compare with the directory name), but then also want to move that same subsetted filename, instead of the original filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a variation of:

```
basedir = "dest/location"

for fname in os.listdir("files/location"):
    dirname = os.path.join(basedir, fname[10:21])
    if os.path.isdir(dirname):
        path = os.path.join("files/location", fname)
        shutil.move(path, dirname)
```

Comment: I think you were right in the first comment you made. If I do the above statement, I get a file or directory doesnt exist error. If I hash out the shutil line and instead do a print("true") if condition is met, it prints true.